# Pass props to child component in React, with Typescript (TSX file)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2013, typescript, jsx, tsx

I am using VS2013 and getting an existing project set up to use React (0.14) and Typescript (1.8.5). My React code works fine as JSX file. I have one error in my new TSX file that I can't figure out.

I have 30 odd errors on every prop pasted to a component down the tree - these all read:

> Property 'nameOfProp' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & {} & { children?: Reac...'.

Here is an example code that gets TypeScript upset. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the one of the last hurdles to get up and running with React in production. NOTE: I have not included information about the App state to save space, but the red lines are only on the child component names (filter, name, id, count)

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    render (
      <FilterItem 
      filter={this.state.artifactFilter}
      count={this.state.count}
      id={this.state.id}
      name={this.state.name}
      />
    )
  }
});
var FilterItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <span>{this.props.name} ({this.props.count})</span>
  )
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The signature for `React.createClass` is:

```
function createClass<P, S>(spec: ComponentSpec<P, S>): ClassicComponentClass<P>;
```

The generic `P` and `S` define the props and state.
The compiler doesn't know what are the types for those and so it uses the base which is the type you get in your error.

You can do:

```
interface AppState {
    filter: string;
    count: number;
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
var App = React.createClass<{}, AppState>(...);

interface FilterItemProps {
    count: number;
    name: string;
}
var FilterItem = React.createClass<FilterItemProps, {}>(...);
```

If you're using classes:

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had experimented with interface, but not properly. This now works. So there is no way to keep prop defining loose? I have to always do an interface declaration, even if I am happy having a non typesafe TSX file?

Comment: You can always use `any, any` for the `T, S`, but then you'll lose type safety. There's no way for the compiler to infer the right types in this case. In my opinion using classes is easier, more readable and just makes more sense, and then adding the generics also doesn't feel as redundant.